# What does it mean "to queer the pudding"?

Tags: idioms, popular-refrains

In today's *Observer*, columnist Jonathan Bouquet mentions Jon Snow on *Channel 4 News* while interviewing Jacob Rees Mogg, having used the expression  *to queer the pudding*. Bouquet refers to it as a "new phrase", to which Rees Mogg is said to have "cocked an eyebrow".

I am quite certain I have heard it, and that it means "to introduce unnecessary complications and confusion to an issue". But I cannot find a reference to it anywhere on line. The only response Google gives me is a reference back to Bouquet's article.

**Please would someone confirm that I am not imagining things when I say it is a well-known saying, perhaps dated, but certainly in 20th century use**.

Comment: I have heard "queer the deal", but...

Comment: @Cascabel Yes, and *the proof is in the pudding*. This particular phrase seems like a confused hybrid of the two.

Comment: @JasonBassford *The proof of the pudding is in the eating* is, I am sure, the original form here.  "Queer the deal" has a slightly different meaning - I think it has been discussed on this site in the last few years.

Comment: @WS2 That's the *original* form of the idiom. It's not the phrasing most commonly used today.

Comment: @JasonBassford Yes the whole topic was discussed here last December - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/476612/alternative-to-queer-the-deal/476682#476682 to which I contributed, but had forgotten. But I don't think I referred to "queer the pudding". You may want to look at that before posting an answer.

Comment: Is it possible Rees "cocked an eyebrow" because of the usage of _queer_ in this context? i.e. gives the appearance of some kind of  reference to LGBTQ?

Comment: sounds s/w familiar ... but it is 'un-findable'

Comment: "...he reacted with a **deliciously** cocked eyebrow at this thought-provoking coinage."

Comment: I think you are imagining things - it sounds like a new coinage to me and isn't to be found either in the BNC or Hansard... but you can see why JRM would love it.

Comment: Maybe it was some kind of conflation of ["overegg the pudding"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pudding) and 'queer the deal'.

Comment: @SConroy Possibly. But I don't understand "queer the pudding" in quite the same way as "overegg the pudding".

Comment: I wonder if its a regional thing from a certain time which is probably what you're asking..

Answer (score 2):

I think this is almost certainly a [brain fart](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/brain+fart), if you like, on Jon Snow's part.

In the heat of the moment, I believe it's entirely possible he corrupted the phrases ['to queer the deal'](https://www.netlingo.com/word/queer-the-deal.php) or possibly ['queer the pitch'](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/queer-the-pitch.html) and ['the proof of the pudding'](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/proof-of-the-pudding.html)

I can only assume this hybridism was sub-conscious/unintentional.

*To queer the pudding* is almost definitely not an existing term; I can't find a mention of it anyway (except for the interview) and it's [not a quote in any books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22to%20queer%20the%20pudding%22).

To back this up, I quote, from the Guardian's Linguistics column:

> *I'm not quite sure what came over Jon Snow ... Interviewing Jacob Rees-Mogg, he introduced a new phrase to the English canon – to queer the pudding.
> ...[Rees-Mogg] reacted with a deliciously cocked eyebrow at this thought-provoking coinage.*

[The Observer (© *The Guardian*)](https://www.theguardian.com/theobserver/commentisfree/2019/jun/23/may-i-have-a-word-about-boris-johnson-tory-leadership-race)

Comment: Cf the complete works of Yogi Berra, American sage.